# Why cannot this simple vector c++ program work?

Tags: c++

I am learning to use stl vector and It is odd that this program cannot work. What is wrong with it? How should I do if I want to implement the same function with vector?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    vector<int>::iterator temp;
    it = vec.begin();
    vec.insert(it, -1);
    it++;
    vec.insert(it, 2);
    for(temp = vec.begin();temp!=vec.end();temp++)
        cout<<*temp<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is not working for you? We are no wizards who can guess what you get and what you expect from your code

Comment: [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) will invalidate all iterators if reallocation should be needed. You should never rely on iterators after changing operations in vector.

Comment: Don't predeclare variables in c++. And using `auto` for iterators is so much easier (and more readable)

Comment: why do you think there is something wrong? When you get an compiler error please include it in the question. When output is not what you expected, please tell us what you expected and what you got instead

Comment: @JHBonarius _"Don't predeclare variables in c++"_... Why ? There are plenty of cases where it is necessary, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Fareanor "plenty of cases"? The *one* case where it can't be avoided is initialising an object from an `istream`

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that was that kind of cases that I had in mind (a container that needs to be filled later,from a file, another thread, etc...)

Comment: it seems that `vector::push_back()` is what you need.

Comment: @Fareanor because it's not C. [C++ Core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-init)

Comment: @JHBonarius In this case, of course, this is useless ! But I was just noticing that there's nothing wrong with predeclaring a variable (and sometimes, you cannot avoid it). What would be wrong is to **access an uninitialized** variable, hence this guideline. So in my opinion, your warning would better be either _"Don't predeclare variables/let them uninitialized **if you can avoid it**"_ or _"Be careful to never access uninitialized variables"_.

Comment: @Fareanor IMHO you're overgeneralizing my comment...

Comment: @JHBonarius Ahah no pb, I understood you from the very beginning. I've just told this to make sure OP understand why you said that, the real reason behind, not that this is bad (indeed the program is well-formed) but what bad things can be possible by doing that. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 7):

`vec.insert(it, -1);` invalidates `it`.

You should rather use `it = vec.insert(it, -1);` which will keep `it` valid.

You can see the documentation:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

section called "Iterator invalidation" or look at this great question and answer: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086)

Comment: [Aggregation and plain English list of all iterator invalidation rules for all Standard Library containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score -7):

On executing the code

```
vector<int> vec;
```

You created an object named vec, it has no elements and `vec.size()` will be zero.

So what `vec.begin()` returns is the same as what `vec.end()` returns.

> By doing `vec.insert(it, -1);` you are inserting a value out of `vec`'s range.
> That is undefined behavior.

No, `vec.insert(it, -1)` works well, but `vec.insert(it, -1)` causes the vector to reallocate memory for its first element.

That invalids `it`.

Try `vec.emplace_back(-1)` or `vec.resize(2)` instead. They extend `vec`'s size and capacity.

Comment: "By doing `vec.insert(it, -1);` you are inserting a value out of `vec`'s range." Why? As explained in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) of the `pos` argument: "_iterator before which the content will be inserted. **pos may be the end() iterator**_" (emphasis - mine).